# How does self.class.where retrieve information from the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One object orientated way to retrieve information from the database is to use those three methods, chained together.

You can create an instance method like this:

```
def "find_friend"
    self.class.where({friend_id: user_id})
end
```

and then call it like this:

```
# @user_friendship == <UserFriendship id: 1, friend_id: 2, user_id: 1>

@user_friendship.find_friend
```

and if we have a user_friendships table like this:

```
| id | friend_id | user_id |

| 1  | 1         | 3       |
| 2  | 2         | 1       |
| 3  | 3         | 2       |
```

Then the find_friend method would return the second record (The one with an id of 2)

```
@user_friendship.find_friend #=> <UserFriendship id: 2, friend_id: 2, user_id: 1>
```

Now, firstly is my understanding correct?

Secondly, how does this actually work? `self.class.inspect` simply returns what appears to be a hash of the model table's schema:

```
self.class.inspect #=> `UserFriendship(id: integer, friend_id: integer, user_id: integer)`
```

So how is it possible to run a query on this simple hash?

```
self.class.where({friend_id: user_id})
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is a class method so it can be called like so.

```
UserFriendship.where({friend_id: user_id})
```

Every Ruby object knows it's own class type so `self.class.where({friend_id: user_id})` is the same thing.  `self.class` resolves to `UserFriendship`, you can then call the where method passing in a hash of key value pairs to pull back the record needed.